# Python Wrapper( for c++ library) generated by swig doesn't work in other system

Tags: python, swig

I create Python wrapper using swig and I gave it to my co-worker who uses the module.

but It doesn't work in his system, though it works well in my system.

i built the wrapper in the system below.

-. OS : windows7 (64bit) (same as him)

-. Target Python module is 3.2.5(32bit) (he is using 3.2(32bit))

-. To generate wrapper, I used Visual Studio 2012(v110)

All generated files are in a list below (and they are all the files that I send to him)

-. pyklt(folder)

-. pyklt/**pycache**(folder, this is generated automatically when I import the module first)

-. pyklt/**init**.py

-. pyklt/_pyklt.pyd

-. pyklt/libklt.dll

-. pyklt/pyklt.py

libklt.dll is referenced by _pyklt.pyd.

This Message below is the Error Message he got. (The Korean String means ' cannot find selected(?) module.' )

```
import pyklt.pyklt
```

File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pyklt\pyklt.py", line 26, in 
    _pyklt = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pyklt\pyklt.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pyklt', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: 지정된 모듈을 찾을 수 없습니다.

Is there anyone can help me? TT
Please tell me if you need more information about the wrapper.

Comment: Have you checked that the generated libklt.dll library doesn't have any dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

If you built the module on Visual Studio 2012, the other person must at least have the [Visual Studio 2012 runtime components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed or the module will failed to load due to the missing dependencies.  Make sure you build a Release version of the module as well.  The Debug runtime components are not redistributable.